# How to Echo div out of form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Need to get div value from form on submit to echo in php

```
<form method="post" action="" id="idme">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="ClaimAmount" name="ClaimAmount"></div>
    </div>
    <input name="subButton" id="SubmitButton" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Won" onclick="showCaptcha();" />

</form>
```

It gets

```
<div id="ClaimAmount" name="ClaimAmount">20</div>
```

from javascrpt fucntion  which has no issue

I am trying to echo this DIV value lik

```
$bonvald =  $this->getPost('ClaimAmount', (int) 0);
```

But instead of getting correct value it always comes as zero

Comment: div has no value better use an input

Comment: How to use input if value is dynamically coming from jquery?

Comment: set that value same way you set in div just use `.val()` ->jquery solution for input

Comment: <script>function showCaptcha(){ var data; data=document.getElementById('ClaimAmount').innerHTML;}</script> usinf this you will get the 'ClaimAmount' data in data variable... same as it is you can set it to any other field...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax post

```
$.ajax({
url:your url
type="post"
data:$('#id').value();
});
```

Or hidden text

Comment: not have much knowledge of ajax way, can you plz give more details how to use or some fiddle plz

Comment: Guradio is said no way just use my advise ajax or input do it 
"div has no value better use an input – guradio"

Answer (score 0):

I have good idea echo dive out you can reference

```
<input name="subButton" id="SubmitButton" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Won" onclick="showCaptcha();" />
<scrip>
function showCaptcha(){
var my_value = $('#id').value();
$('form').append('<input type='hidden' value='YourValue' name="YourTextName">');
$('form').submit();
}
</scrip>
```